# svn client timeout on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, svn, tortoise-svn

I upgraded my PC to Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium - clean install. Since then I've tried to install the following SVN clients: Tortois 1.6.6 64bit and 32bit, Tortois 1.6.5 64bit, SlikSVN, SmartSVN, and a couple others. None of them will connect to ANY remote SVN repository.

Note: Everything works correctly when I plug in my old Vista HD with Tortoise 1.6.6 client installed. Therefore, I do not suspect the network per se.

I've seen some posts around with people running into similar issues on Windows 7 64bit but I've yet to see an actual answer/solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After turning gaming mode on/off I was seeing inconsistent behavior. I resolved it by opening port 3690 outbound TCP in Windows 7 firewall.

Comment: I'm finally onto something. I turned on "Gaming" mode in BitDefender Anti-Virus. Re-installed Tortois SVN 64bit v1.6.6 and restarted the machine. SVN connectivity now works. I will respond again after I run the reverse test by turning off the "Gaming" mode to see if I once again get blocked from SVN access.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with running Tortoise 64-bit on one of the Windows 7 64-bit beta builds. Running it in Vista compatibility mode solved the problem.

- Right Click on the installed Tortoise binary
- You will get the properties screen, navigate to the **compatibility** tab as shown here:

  [image]
- Try running it in compatibility mode for Vista SP2. If it doesn't work, go back a service pack or even back to plain Vista. SP2 worked for me.

Comment: Tried Windows XP and Vista with no luck. It wasn't just Tortois, it was also SmartSVN and every other SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dumb question, but have you checked that your firewall is blocking the ports that your svn clients use?

- svn:// - Port 3690
- http:// - Port 80
- svn+ssh:// - Port 22

I recently did a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate x64, and had to open a few ports, before I could talk to my Subversion server.

Answer (score 0):

check out the post to run SVN in windows 7.

http://thinkdiff.net/mixed-topis/running-subversion-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

For any future cases, I was having the exact same problem, all svn clients I tried failed to connect to my svn server, but I figured out after many days that bitdefender feature of "Antivirus - Real Time Protection" messed with the connection, so I disabled this feature and problem solved. I could connect to my svn server from any svn client I had.

Specifically I was having problems with unfuddle.com